# Stop cell from animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation

In my tableView I'm using custom cells with two custom labels. Eventually the text of these labels will change but at the same time, `layoutIfNeeded()` is called to animate some other things. This is causing the text in the labels to animate as well which I'm trying to prevent.

The code I'm using to change the text:

```
func tapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: myData.count - 1, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as! CustomCell

    cell.infoLabel.text = "Changing text here"

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { self.anotherView.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

To prevent the labels from animating I have tried adding this in `CustomLabel` and `CustomCell`, as well as in `willDisplayCell`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation { super.layoutSubviews() }
}
```

Or using another way of preventing it to animate in `CustomLabel` and `CustomCell`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    super.layoutSubviews()

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

I've also tried a property observer setting the text and removing all animations at the same time:

```
var text: String { 
    didSet { 
        infoLabel.text = text
        infoLabel.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work **unless** I use:

```
CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
cell.infoLabel.text = "Changing text here"

CATransaction.commit()
```

But then I'd have to use it everywhere I'm changing the text. Is there a place I've overlooked to do this more elegantly?

Comment: What is it you're trying to animate? Also, FYI it's generally not good practice to use let cellForRowAtIndexPath. You should instead change your model and reload the tableview, or subclass the cell and handle the behavior there.

Comment: The table view itself has been lay out with auto layout and when I tap something, a custom number pad will show up at the bottom. To prevent content of the table view being hidden behind the number pad, I resize the table view. The reason I'm using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is because depending on the situation, cell's might be added. If I simply reload the table view, then the animation of adding the cell would be impossible? (Havent looked up how to create custom animation for adding cells yet).